# Change image tint, title tint, background and so on in new UITabbar from iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbarappearance

I faced a weird problem. I wanted to change the colors of my tabBar in just one of my view controllers of my tabBar. How do I achieve this in iOS > 13?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot and finding no working solutions, I succeeded by luck.
I found out that you must set an appearance object before I can change them!!
But if you set appearance before the `override function endAppearanceTransition()` of UITabbar it is working, but not anymore. finally, this way worked:

1. Set an empty appearance object at viewDidLoad of one of the view Controllers or UITabbarViewcontroller to be executed one time:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       tabBarController?.tabBar.standardAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
   }
   ```
2. Then you can use updating like this at anytime:

   ```
   let attrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green]
   tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundColor = barColor
   tabBarController?.tabBar.standardAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = .green
   tabBarController?.tabBar.standardAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = .green
   tabBarController?.tabBar.standardAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = attrs
   tabBarController?.tabBar.standardAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = attrs
   ```